# SPView.RenderAsHTML() Paging and Filtering not working

Tags: development, office-365, list-view, custom-list, spview

I have displayed a sharepoint list view on webpart using [SPView.RenderAsHtml()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442053.aspx) method with following code:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("List1");
SPView myView = list.DefaultView;
sb.Append("<p>" + myView.RenderAsHtml() + "</p>");
Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

No problem in displaying view but **Paging & Filtering for the view is not working on Office365** as it is working fine on on-premise.

[image]

I have already set a `Paged='TRUE'` for the view,

```
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">5</RowLimit>
```

When I am clicking on NextPage button then page url is changing to

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/SitePages/DemoPage.aspx?Paged=TRUE&p_ID=5&View={A9B85255-1F96-456C-AE17-6156175ACC0F}&PageFirstRow=6
```

but actual paging not working.

Any Solution ?